# DropzoneJS - create own function to upload files

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I use DropzoneJS library to upload files on my website. Now, I want to create my own function to upload queued files.

I know, I can get all these files in that way:

```
files = myDropzone.getQueuedFiles();
```

But how I can now create an ajax request to send these files? I need something like `file_get_contents()` function (as in PHP) to get content of these files and then send ajax post with that params.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can specify your url you want to be fired when all your files gets processed

Comment: url: "class/inserir.php?funcao=teste",

Comment: I have a long form on my website and I send everything in this request. In DropzoneJS I have to set next URL to upload files - I do not want it. I want to add to my current ajax these files and send one request but I don't know how I can create this ajax request using `getQueuedFiles()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could give a bit more context. If I understand correctly:

```
function sendFile(file) {
   // Do ajax things here e.g. check out the link below
}


const files = myDropzone.getQueuedFiles(); // I'm assuming this returns an array?
files.forEach(sendFile) // For each loops over the array, and calls the sendFile function with as first parameter the current item in the array, which is in your case one of your files
```

To make an AJAX request with vanilla javascript: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: is it possible to send ajax request in that way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24939229/10210622 ?

Comment: that's using jQuery. Checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest to do it without jQuery